# How to make a Button Clickable in a ListView generated using a SimpleAdapter in Android?

Tags: android, listview, button, simpleadapter

I have generated a `Listview` using a `SimpleAdapter` in Android. I have placed a few `TextViews` and a `Button` in a `Xml` file so that these widgets get displayed on the row of the ListView. I want to make the Button clickable in the ListView. I don't want to use any `BaseAdapter` or `CustomAdapter` or an `Arrayadapter`.Can anyone suggest me how to do with a simpleadapter?

My codes are as follows:

```
     final ListView l=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
     ListAdapter k=new SimpleAdapter(this,val1,R.layout.mytask,new String[]{"TaskId","heading","status"},new int[]{R.id.View1,R.id.View2,R.id.ViewStatus});
     Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mytask);
     l.setAdapter(k);
```

My xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 

>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="Task Name:"

    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/View1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="TextView"

    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/View2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="TextView"

    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ViewStatus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/View2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/View2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Pending"

    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ViewStatus"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ViewStatus"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ViewStatus"
    android:text="Status:"

    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/mytask"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: Add an OnClickListener to the button...

Comment: Doesn't work. Gives force closs

Comment: Post your adapter code, @ElDuderino is correct.

Comment: please check the codes

Comment: Can you post the logcat when you get the exception? Also posting the entire adapter will be useful

Comment: this is all wrong, obviously button is not created until getView is called, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `SimpleAdapter` yet override `getView`. You should check the docs on how `getView` works, by how you were trying to accomplish it, seems you don't understand very well the adapter basics: Your button will only be created when ListView generates the different rows, something that at the first time, happens asynchronously at some point in the future after you set the adapter.

```
ListAdapter k=new SimpleAdapter(this,val1,R.layout.mytask,new String[]{"TaskId","heading","status"},new int[]{R.id.View1,R.id.View2,R.id.ViewStatus}) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // get filled view from SimpleAdapter
        View itemView=super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        // find our button there
        View myTaskButton=itemView.findViewById(R.id.mytask);
        // add an onClickListener
        myTaskButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // your button is pressed on this view  
            }
        });
        return itemView;
    }
};
```

or better yet, avoid creating objects inside getView() so pre-create a listener that you will reuse:

```
OnClickListener mTaskClickListener=new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         // your button is pressed on this view, position is stored in tag. 
         Integer positionPressed=(Integer)v.getTag();
    }
};
ListAdapter k=new SimpleAdapter(this,val1,R.layout.mytask,new String[]{"TaskId","heading","status"},new int[]{R.id.View1,R.id.View2,R.id.ViewStatus}) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // get filled view from SimpleAdapter
        View itemView=super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        // find our button there
        View myTaskButton=itemView.findViewById(R.id.mytask);

        // add an onClickListener, but this time is alredy created and the same for all
        myTaskButton.setOnClickListener(mTaskClickListener);
        myTaskButton.setTag(position); // so we know which tag was pressed
        return itemView;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You could override getView, but then you can use any other adapter too ... SimpleAdapter is just to map strings to a view, nothing else.